# Can not connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, tcp, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to configure a freshly installed MySQL server to listen on port 3306.

I've removed `skip_networking`, I have changed `bind-address=172.20.33.1` (which is my server's IP) and it completely ignores the config.

When I try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking'` I see it's still frustratingly ON.

`netstat -na | grep mysql` indicates it's not listening as it returns nothing.

Running on Ubuntu 12.04.2

Am I missing something **really** obvious?

Comment: Questions about server software configuration belong on Server Fault, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, do you *really* want to expose a freshly installed instance to the Internet?  There's a reason networking is disabled by default...

Comment: The ip address above is not my real ip. I just need my application to be able to connect to my mysql database. Currently my server isnt listening to port 3306. I believe skip-networking is preventing this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mysql is not installed properly. Run through a proper LAMP install with tasksel: sudo apt-get install tasksel

Install LAMP server

Then check to see if you can log into the server.